# Cannot implicitly convert type "string" to "bool" when using if condition?

Tags: asp.net, textbox

When I write if condition in one line for the textbox i.e.

`if (txtNotes.Text.Equals("&nbsp;") ? string.Empty: gvrow.Cells[6].Text)`

I am getting the error stating:

> **Cannot implicitly convert type "string" to "bool"**

Just want to check where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the standard `if` statement syntax with the ternary operator `?:`. It's either:

```
txtNotes.Text = txtNotes.Text.Equals("&nbsp;") ? string.Empty : gvrow.Cells[6].Text;
```

or

```
if (txtNotes.Text.Equals("&nbsp;"))
{
    txtNotes.Text = string.Empty;
}
else
{
    txtNotes.Text = gvrow[6].Cells.Text;
}
```

Edit: from your comment you've stated your setting the value of `txtNotes.Text`, so I recommend using the ternary operator to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks robyaw. actually I am pulling the data from the database, and populating the textbox (txtnotes). If the data equals &nbsp; then txtNotes.text should be empty otherwise it will pull the data from the gridviewrow (gvrow.Cells[6].Text)